# Use function script-wide?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, web-services, websocket

Experimenting  with the ws library for node.js but I have been struggling with a problem all morning.

Here is my current code:

```
var MySQLEvents = require('mysql-events');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
  ws.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message)
  })

  ws.send("hey mane");

})

var dsn = {
  host:     'localhost',
  user:     'root',
  password: ''
};
var myCon = MySQLEvents(dsn);

var event1 = myCon.add(
  'db.test.name.value',
  function (oldRow, newRow, event) {
    if (oldRow !== null && newRow !== null) {
      console.log("DB change")
    }
  }, 
  'Active'
);

var MySQLEvents = require('mysql-events');
var dsn = {
  host:     'localhost',
  user:     'root',
  password: '',
};
var mysqlEventWatcher = MySQLEvents(dsn);
var watcher =mysqlEventWatcher.add(
  'experimental.test',
  function (oldRow, newRow, event) {
      console.log(event);
     //row inserted 
    if (oldRow === null) {
      console.log("Row inserted");
    }

     //row deleted 
    if (newRow === null) {
      console.log("Row deleted");
    }

     //row updated 
    if (oldRow !== null && newRow !== null) {
        console.log("Row updated");
    }

    //detailed event information 
    //console.log(event);
  }, 

);
```

Notice this part of the code:

```
wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
  ws.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message)
  })

  ws.send("hey mane");

})
```

Here a function called `ws` is created, but the problem for me is that it's only possible to use it inside this little code bracket. I want to do `ws.send('hello');` further down in the code but then an error saying that `ws` is not defined is shown. How do I make `ws` work across the entire script?

UPDATE:
I want `ws.send` right here:

```
//row inserted 
    if (oldRow === null) {
      **HERE**
    }

     //row deleted 
    if (newRow === null) {
      **HERE**
    }

     //row updated 
    if (oldRow !== null && newRow !== null) {
        **HERE**


}
```

Client

```
url = "ws://localhost:8080";
ws = new WebSocket(url);

// event emmited when connected
    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log('websocket is connected ...');
        // sending a send event to websocket server
        ws.send('connected');
    }
    // event emmited when receiving message 
    ws.onmessage = function (ev) {
        console.log(ev.data);
    }
```

Comment: Keep all `ws` related code inside the function block in which `ws.send("hey mane");` already resides.

Comment: There is no function called `ws`.  It's just a parameter of the anonymous function.  `wss` should be available everywhere you need it.

Comment: can you tell us where "further down in the code" you would like to use it?

Comment: "Further down" means outside the `wss.on` block, I assume? That's not how this works; you need to set up everything inside there. This is pure event-based programming, and it works a bit differently than what you're used to, I guess. If you need to use `ws` together with other data, declare the `var`s on top of your script, so you can use them inside the `wss.on` block.

Comment: what i wanted to lead at is that if the "further down" is sequentially placed just after, no chance. But if it's in another event handler that's supposed to happen after, it should be possible to declare a `var` at the top of the script and give it the `ws` value when it arrives (at connection), and those handlers could access it. Of course, there should be handling for multiple connections (array of ws) and test to know if the var exists before trying to send with it

Comment: To expand a bit on my previous comment: in the long run one would of course keep track of all connections in an array so messages can be broadcast to all connected users and the like, but for now it seems much more important to understand the event based nature of socket programming (as opposed to a program that runs more or less from top to bottom, like a recipe)

Comment: You need to show us EXACTLY where you're trying to call `ws.send()`.  The complication here is that this is a server that serves the needs of many users.  `ws` belongs to ONE particular user.  So, wherever you want to call `ws.send()`, you have to figure out how to get the correct `ws` object that matches the desired user.  There is not only one `ws`.  There are lots - one for every user that connects to your server.  So, we need to see more of the problem and understand what context you're trying to do `ws.send()` and for what user you want to send.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated the OP where I want to have it.

Comment: That's not enough context.  We need to see the entire request handler that it's in AND, we need to know how you would know WHICH user or all the users that might be connected to your server that you want to `ws.send()` to.  I'm not sure you understood everything in my previous comment.  Keep in mind there could be 100 users currently connected to your server and there's a `ws` object for every one of them.  How do you know which of those 100 `ws` objects you want to use?

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually, in this project I want each and every user to see the same results. I'm not completely sure on what you mean when you want me to show the entire request handler, but he'res the client:

Comment: url = "ws://localhost:8080";
ws = new WebSocket(url);

// event emmited when connected
    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log('websocket is connected ...');
        // sending a send event to websocket server
        ws.send('connected');
    }
    // event emmited when receiving message 
    ws.onmessage = function (ev) {
        console.log(ev.data);
    }

Comment: If you want to send the data to EVERY connected user, then there's an example in the `ws` doc [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#broadcast-example).  You iterate `wss.clients` and send to every connected client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the data to EVERY connected user (which you now state in your comment), then there's an example in the `ws` doc [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#broadcast-example).  You iterate `wss.clients` and send to every connected client:

```
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      client.send(data);
    }
  });
```